# Unabled to connect samsung mobile phone (bluetooth/usb) both to my linux box

Tags: mobile, ubuntu, bluetooth, gprs

I tried all the the different stuff. But its not working. Its something general to linux. I have tried it in Arch Linux and now I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 beta2 also its the same there. I am trying to connect my Samsung mobile phone to my ubuntu box for gprs, buts its not working. I have tried bluetooth and usb both. It pairs fine with bluetooth but on using DUN service or browsing file etc.. it just crashes ... like the phone is not responding to its requests. I have upgraded the kernel to 3.3 from ubuntu PPA. Thought that might solve the problem. But its the same. I have downloaded blueman from another PPA. Which also finds phones, gets paired but whenever I try to browse file, send file or use DUN it says my phone is not responding. I have tried mannual rfcomm bind 0... stuff it creates a /dev/rfcomm0 and when you cat > /dev/rfcomm0 it communitcates with phone and asks for pin code etc... but when i do pppd... chat dailing ... logs says the same no response from my phone. Please guide me ... what should I do. Just for the info. Phone works fine on windows. I am using it right now. Regards

Comment: do you have a udev rules file for that phone mfg'r? I had to manually add mine for an HTC EVO in Ubuntu.   http://forums.androidcentral.com/linux/57132-how-set-up-udev-rules-ubuntu-10-10-a.html

Comment: thanks for the reply buddy! let me check.

Comment: nope... it din't worked out that way. I think its something with the latest kernel series 3.x As paring is working and whenever pc communicates with mobile... bluetooth icon blinks ... means communication is taking place between the two... so there something wrong with bluetooth driver in kernel

Answer (score 0):

You shall try this project: [Android File Transfer For Linux](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux)